# Ionic 2 - Access ngModel in controller

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I'd like to access my ngModel in a controller, for some reason I can't find out how to do it. I've got a `radio-group` (which does not belong to a form, but just to a splashscreen where users can personalize the application.

**My html:**

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="language">
    <ion-list-header style="word-break: normal;">
        {{ languageText }}
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Nederlands</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="nl"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>English</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="eng"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Deutsch</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="du"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**I want to access the `ngModel: language` in my controller:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-intro',
  templateUrl: 'intro.html'
})

export class IntroPage {

  welcomeTitle: any;
  languageText: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public storage: Storage) {

    this.displayLanguage();
  }

  finishIntro() {

    this.storage.set('introShown', true);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }

  displayLanguage() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ngModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel) is the two-binding functionality from Angular 2.

If you are having

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="language">
```

`language` needs to be a variable in your **component**.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-intro',
  templateUrl: 'intro.html'
})

export class IntroPage {

  welcomeTitle: any;
  languageText: any;
  language:any;//here
```

Any change in language in the html or component side is reflected in the other.

Comment: I see, but what I want to know is how to do something like this:
`if(language.selected = "nl") {
 // do something
}`

Comment: that will be `if(language == "n1"){//do something}` also check http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/radio/RadioGroup/